# Ability to only see the content of the profile that has been filled out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

so I've created a web app that has user profiles, where users can search for fellow users based on interests etc.. However sometimes the users don't fill out certain areas of their profile, i.e. about me may be left blank.. So how can I add the ability for users to only see the content of the profile that they filled out. In other words they can’t see the parts of other user profiles for which they have not completed.

**user_profile.html.erb**

```
<%= render "shared/header" %>

<div id="landing_welcome_page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <%#= Profile image upload  %>
      <div class="span4">
        <%= user_avatar(current_user) %>
        <%#= Space w line  %>
        <div class="name"></div><br>

        <%#= Please bare in mind these are strickly temporary placeholders i.e whitespace  %>
        <%= render 'social' %>
      </div>

      <div class="span8">
        <%# User name %>

          <span class="name1">
            <% if current_user.first_name.blank? %>
            <%= current_user.first_name.present? ? current_user.first_name : link_to('Finish your profile', edit_account_path)%>
            <% else %>
            <%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %>
            <% end %>
          </span>
          <span class="side-buttons">
        <div class="name"></div>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <br />
        <div class="span6">
          <%# User occupation %>
          <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>:
          <%= best_in_place current_user, :occupation, nil: 'Add occupation' %>
        </div>

        <div class="addy">
          <div class="span2">
           <%# User address %>
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>:
           <%= current_user.address.present? ? current_user.address : link_to('Add Address', edit_account_path) %>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="span6">
         <%# User gender %>
     <br />
         <% if current_user.gender == "M" || "male" %>
         <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
         <% else %>
         <i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
         <% end %>
       </div>

       <div class="span2">
         <!-- Code to calculate age by user birthday -->
     <br />
         Age: <%= user_birthday %>
       </div>

       <div class="span8"></div>

       <div class="span8"><div class="name"></div></div>
       <div class="span8">
        <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Personality</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane in active" id="tab1">
              <% @questions_for_about.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
              <div class="question">
                <h4 class="user_questions">
                  <%= index + 1 %>. <%= question.question %>
                  <%= link_to ("<i class='icon-edit'></i>".html_safe),
                  edit_user_question_path(current_user, question),
                  remote: true, class: "edit_link_#{question.id}" %>
                </h4>
                <div class="answer" id="answer_<%= question.id %>">
                  <%= answer_for(question) %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
              <div class="page-header">
                <%= form_for Photo.new do |f| %>
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                  <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                  <span>Add photos...</span>
                  <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "photo[file]" %>
                </span>
                <% end %>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="photos_cont">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <span class="gallery"><%= render current_user.photos %></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
              <% @questions_for_personality.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
              <div class="question">
                <h4 class="user_questions">
                  <%= index + 1 %>. <%= question.question %>
                  <%= link_to ("<i class='icon-edit'></i>".html_safe),
                  edit_user_question_path(current_user, question),
                  remote: true, class: "edit_link_#{question.id}" %>
                </h4>
                <div class="answer" id="answer_<%= question.id %>">
                  <%= answer_for(question) %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render '/shared/footer' %>
  </div>
</div>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div class="upload">
{%=o.name%}
<div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
</div>
</script>
<script>
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = '6009056882201';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>

<noscript>
  <img height="1" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=6009056882201&amp;value=0" style="display:none;" width="1"/>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
// remove default datepicker event
jQuery(document).off('best_in_place:datepicker');

jQuery(document).on('best_in_place:datepicker', function(event, bip, element) {
  // Display the jQuery UI datepicker popup
  jQuery(element).find('input')
  .datepicker({
    format: element.data('date-format')
  })
  .on('hide', function(){
    bip.update();
  })
  .on('changeDate', function(){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
  })
  .datepicker('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This question was asked nearly a month ago. Have you had a chance to review any of the provided answers?

Answer (score 1):

The conditionals that you have can be expanded to cover the whole `div` containing the info block.

For example:

```
<div class="addy">
      <div class="span2">
       <%# User address %>
       <i class="fa fa-home"></i>:
       <%= current_user.address.present? ? current_user.address : link_to('Add Address', edit_account_path) %>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Could be

```
<div class="addy">
  <% if current_user.address.present? %>
      <div class="span2">
         <%# User address %>
         <i class="fa fa-home"></i>:
         <%= current_user.address %>
       </div>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to('Add Address', edit_account_path) %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

Then it would only show the link if the address is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're on the right track. Basically, for every user attribute on the `User` model you want to show/hide, you'll want to add a conditional that evaluates whether or not the attribute on `current_user` is `present?`:

```
<span class="name1">
    <% if current_user.first_name.blank? %>
        <%= link_to('Finish your profile', edit_account_path) %>
    <% else %>
        <%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %>
    <% end %>
</span>
```

Alternatively, you can continue using ternary operators for single line evaluations, as you are already doing in some instances:

```
<%= current_user.address.present? ? current_user.address : link_to('Add Address', edit_account_path) %>
```